# webservice referer

Tags: httpwebrequest, http-headers, websphere, webservices-client

It's possible to get the webservice caller url referer? If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is for Microsoft non-WCF webservices. I am sure there is something equivalent for WCF as well.

When your webservice is invoked, you can get a handle to the [Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.aspx). The context will give you access to the [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) object from which you can query any header.